# How to add a checkbox control to a datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

How can i add a checkbox to a datatable and bind it to a datagrid?

```
DataTable ColumnList = new DataTable();
ColumnList.Columns.Add("Column Fields");

int j = 1, i = 0;
CheckBox colCheckbox = new CheckBox();
foreach (Columns col in ColumnNames)
{
    colCheckbox.Name = col.ColumnName;       
    ColumnList.Rows.Add(colCheckbox); // This is getting displayed as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox,CheckState=0
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Is this winforms? WPF? asp.net?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You're confounding visual controls and data sources: You *cannot* add a checkbox to a `DataTable` because a check box is a visual control, while a `DataTable` is only data. You can, however, add a checkbox column to a `DataGridView` (which *is* a visual control that can be data-bound to a `DataTable`).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You'll have to have a `boolean` field (column) in the DataTable. When you bind the DataTable to the DataGridView, a checkbox column will be created for that `boolean` field.

**Sample Code:**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selected", typeof(bool))); //this will show checkboxes
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(string)));   //this will show text

var dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

This will bind the `dt` DataTable to the `dgv` DataGridView. The DataGridView will automatically display a [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx) for the first DataColumn (*Selected*) and a [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.aspx) for the second DataColumn (*Text*).

Comment: +1. I'd add to your answer that the visual column that is automatically created is a [`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx), in case that the OP wants to add it manually.

Comment: is it possible to display both the CheckBox and text in one column, when DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn is used? How can i bind both?

Comment: You can't have text in a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. The text will appear in a different column. See my revision for how to do that.

Comment: Dim colItem3 As New DataColumn("columnName", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))
Dim colItem4 As New DataColumn("columnName2", Type.GetType("System.String"))
also works.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the type of the column.

```
ColumnList.Columns.Add("Column Fields", gettype(CheckBox));
```

But why do you want to add a control to a DataTable? Why not just a string or an integer?

Comment: But this is not displaying any checkboxes in the datagrid. I need to bind checkboxes to the grid with some text bound to the checkbox.

Comment: You have to add a DataGridCheckBoxColumn to the Datagrid and bind that column to a field in the DataTable. There's no need to add a checkbox to the DataTable.